# Python: BeautifulSoup - extract value from location.href=

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I encountered a problem statement where I need to print the value "input.php?id=293" of the key "location.href=" from the code.

```
<script>location.href="input.php?id=293";</script>
```

I have tried the below code but stuck in the end.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = https://localhost/sample.php
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")
value = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'location.href'))
print (value)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = BeautifulSoup('<script>location.href="input.php?id=293";</script>')
data.get_text()[15:-2]
```

Comment: Hey Alona! Thanks for the response. I tried your code and it gave me a blank response.
Is it possible to retrieve the value without making It a static text?

Comment: @Alex, but can you get any value just by trying data.get_text()?

Comment: No data, the program just returns
' '.

We need to soup.find_all to find our data right?

Comment: @Alex, there are several methods that can be used: find_all(), find(), find_parents(), find_previous_siblings(), find_all_next(), find_all_previous() etc. But first two ones are the most used

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """<script>location.href="input.php?id=293";</script>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r'("input\.php\?id=293")')
value = soup.find_all(text=pattern)
result = pattern.search(str(value)).group()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
"input.php?id=293"
```